# Get last value of certain class using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've got a table in html that looks like this:

```
<tbody id="letter-list">
    <?php
    $index = 0;
    foreach($letters as $letter)
    {
        $index++;
    ?>
    <tr id="letter-<?php echo $index; ?>">
        <td><?php echo $letter->contractor->short_name; ?> </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $letter->contractor->address ?><br />
            <?php echo $letter->contractor->postal_code," ",$letter->contractor->city; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
           <a title="Usuń" class="btn btn-danger del-letter" href="#" id="del-letter-<?php echo $index; ?>"
              data-url="<?php echo $delete_url."/".$letter->id; ?>" data-index="<?php echo $index; ?>">
               <i class="icon-remove"></i> &nbsp; usuń
           </a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

As you see I'm generating a table with php object but I need to last `data-index` of `del-letter` class and have no idea how to do this using jQuery.

Comment: What do you mean by `I need to last data-index of del-letter class`??

Comment: On each <a> there is a custom data-index atribute i need to get last a cutrom attr value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get what you are looking for:

```
var lastDataIndex = $('.del-letter:last').data('index');
```